# Are there any levels that restrict how many Zoombinis you are able to save?

Tags: zoombinis

For the most part, I have found that most of the levels (while not so obvious) always allow the entire group of 16 Zoombinis to complete a puzzle.

However, the last level where they are required to travel across the grid in bubbles, the last two attempts I have been unsuccessful in getting the entire group across, try as I might.

Is this planned?

**Note:** The first time, I only had 15 Zoombinis when I came to the last puzzle, and I only lost 1. The second time I had 16, but I lost 5. This *may* have some influence over what's currently happening.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're forced to lose some, but my memory doesn't go back 20 years so idk.

Comment: @Aequitas I know them feels :P

Comment: Lol in BubbleWonder Abyss I lost my Zoombinis because they bumped into one another. At least your Zoombinis have an honorable reason of dea- I mean . . . return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not forced to lose them.

In BubbleWonder Abyss, there are many ways to cross. You must look at the entire level before sending Zoombinis across. If one path has you alternating between Zoombinis with rollerblades and Zoombinis without rollerblades, then you should look at the number of Zoombinis without rollerblades and send the ones not needed for other paths first.

The problem with BubbleWonder Abyss is that it is easy to not lose them in the spirals but they are left behind too often. In this level, if you need Zoombinis with rollerblades for the pattern, it doesn't make sense for you to send them where they aren't needed. However, after a long and frustrating journey (I didn't like that pizza the FIRST time!), sometimes you just want to get it over with.

Comment: I'm also sure there is a structure that can be built if you get all Zoombinis to ZoombiniVille without losing any.